# Obter o usuário logado no form

Tags: django

Olá! Estou precisando obter o usuário que está logado na minha aplicação, pois no form tenho campos modelChoice, e as query precisam trazer por usuário logado, como mostra abaixo:

Obs: Trabalho com com class based view.

Obs2: Django 1.10

```
from django import forms
from core.models.documento import *
from core.models.forma_pagamento import *
from core.models.local_compra import *
from core.models.tipo_documento import *

class DocumentoForm(forms.ModelForm):
   descricao = forms.CharField(label='Descrição:')
   forma_pagamento = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Forma de pagamento:',queryset=FormaPagamento.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Documento
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que fazer um override do init do seu form.

```
class MeuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MeuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        usuario = kwargs['initial']['usuario']
        self.fields['forma_pagamento'].queryset = FormaPagamento.objects.filter(usuario=usuario)
```

Eu não entendi o filtro que você quer fazer mas acredito que dê pra compreender.

Na sua view, como está utilizando class based view, vale a pena dar uma lida na documentação. Mas você tem que sobrescrever um método existente para que seja enviado o usuário para o form.

```
class MinhaView(CreateView):
    ...
    def get_initial(self):
        return {'usuario':self.request.user}
```

Comment: Já consegui resolver, lendo muito a doc. Fiz dessa forma, vlw.